# how to keep the display on the current slide [javascript slider] after submit button is pressed

Tags: php, javascript, email, contact-form

Situation:

I have a webpage utilzing a javascript slider [tiny slider from scriptiny dot com].
I created a contact form on the last slide with jquery validation and php validation.
Everything works fine EXCEPT for:
After clicking on Submit, the webpage displays the first slide.
Not sure hot to make it stick to the contact "slide".

Site navigation is done using a string like:

```
onclick="slideshow.pos(0)  
onclick="slideshow.pos(1)  
onclick="slideshow.pos(2)  
onclick="slideshow.pos(3)  
onclick="slideshow.pos(4)
```

I need the contact "slide" to stay on "slideshow.pos(4)".

Code:

```
//If there is no error, send the email 
if(!isset($hasError)){ 
    $emailTo = 'myemail@gmail.com'; //Put your own email address here 
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $comments"; 
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email; 
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers); 
    $emailSent = true; 
}
```

How can I do this? Ideally, I would be able to run some javascript after the email is sent making the refresh of the page send the user to "slideshow.pos(4)"??
Any help would be appreciated,

Mark

Comment: Can you post the code you have questions about so SO can better assist you?

Answer (score 0):

You can "submit" your data with an Ajax call and avoid the page from refreshing in the first place. If you never used Ajax take some time to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax.